# Конструктор объектов

Tags: swift, spritekit

Здравствуйте! Помогите новичку...
У нас есть один объект. Для примера:

```
var ball = SKSpriteNode()
ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
ball.size = CGSize(какой-то размер)
ball.zPosition = 5
addChild(ball)
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как сделать конструктор для данного объекта? Необходимо, чтобы данный объект копировался и появлялся в одной из рандомной позиции (которые были заранее заданы).
Еще хотелось бы задавать интервал времени, с которым будут появляться новые объекты.
Как сделать в теории конечно представляю. Но вот с кодом самостоятельно разобраться не получается(((

Answer (score 2):

Создайте класс с вашим объектом. После этого сможете создавать сколько угодно экземпляров этого класса.

По поводу появления через заданное время - используйте `dispatch_after`